# Tamper monkey script doesn't behave the same on different machines and browsers

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         responsive design
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  Take screenshot
// @author       You
// @match        https://example.com
// @grant        none
// @require      https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.5.0-beta4/html2canvas.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    'use strict';
    var overrideRadioButtonToChoose = -1;
    var allowDuplicateResponses = false;
    var powerToRaiseRandomNumberTo = 1;
    var radioButtonNames = new Array();
    function addName(radioButtonName) {
        var uniqueName = true;
        for (
            var nameCounter = 0;
            nameCounter < radioButtonNames.length;
            nameCounter++
        ) {
            if (radioButtonNames[nameCounter] == radioButtonName) {
                uniqueName = false;
            }
        }
        if (uniqueName == true) {
            radioButtonNames.push(radioButtonName);
        }
    }
    function findRadioButtons() {
        var documentElements = document.forms[0].elements;
        for (
            var elementCounter = 0;
            elementCounter < documentElements.length;
            elementCounter++
        ) {
            if (documentElements[elementCounter].type == 'radio') {
                addName(documentElements[elementCounter].name);
            }
        }
    }
    function setRadioButtons() {
        var radioToSelect;
        var numberOfRadioButtons = document.getElementsByName(radioButtonNames[0])
        .length;
        var usedRadioButton = new Array(numberOfRadioButtons);
        for (var RBCounter = 0; RBCounter < numberOfRadioButtons; RBCounter++) {
            usedRadioButton[RBCounter] = false;
        }
        for (
            var RBGroupCounter = 0;
            RBGroupCounter < radioButtonNames.length;
            RBGroupCounter++
        ) {
            if (overrideRadioButtonToChoose > -1) {
                radioToSelect = overrideRadioButtonToChoose;
            } else {
                radioToSelect = Math.floor(
                    Math.pow(Math.random(), powerToRaiseRandomNumberTo) *
                    numberOfRadioButtons
                );
                if (!allowDuplicateResponses) {
                    while (
                        usedRadioButton[
                            (radioToSelect = Math.floor(
                                Math.pow(Math.random(), powerToRaiseRandomNumberTo) *
                                numberOfRadioButtons
                            ))
                        ]
                    ) {}
                }
            }
            document.forms[0][radioButtonNames[RBGroupCounter]][
                radioToSelect
            ].checked = true;
            usedRadioButton[radioToSelect] = true;
        }
    }
    var pageTitle = document.title.replace(/ /g,"_");
    var pageName = document.getElementsByTagName('h2')[0].textContent.replace(/ /g,"_");
    takeScreenShot(`${pageTitle}-${pageName}.png`);

    function takeScreenShot(filename) {
        html2canvas(document.body)
            .then(function(canvas) {
            saveAs(canvas.toDataURL(), filename);
        })
            .then(() => {
            findRadioButtons();
            setRadioButtons();
            var nextButtonCollection = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-next');
            nextButtonCollection[0].click();
        });
    }

    function saveAs(uri, filename) {
        var link = document.createElement('a');

        if (typeof link.download === 'string') {
            link.href = uri;
            link.download = filename;

            //Firefox requires the link to be in the body
            document.body.appendChild(link);

            //simulate click
            link.click();

            //remove the link when done
            document.body.removeChild(link);
        } else {
            window.open(uri);
        }
    }
}, false);
```

The above tamper monkey script works fine for me on chrome. However on someone else's chrome it does one page and then get stuck. Also on Firefox for me it downloads the first image and fills in the radiobuttons but never clicks the next button for some reason.

I've checked the page it is being used on and it doesn't use any ajax requests on the next button (changed the site url for this example as it's internal).

Is there anything obviously wrong with my script that is making it behave differently on different browsers.

Comment: What browser versions and what Tampermonkey versions?  Also, please verify that you are not trying Greasemonkey 4+. ... Finally, **the question is incomplete without a link to the target page or a suitable [mcve] thereof.**

Comment: (A) You should be seeing errors on the console when it doesn't work, and (B) that `Math.pow(Math.random()...` code is "time bomb code" and may be causing random index violations.